# SQL Server Stored Procs include file statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, include

I don't think it is possible to do so what I would but I ask anyway.

I've found that I include the same variables in the top of every Stored Proc I make.
These variables are used for logging and error handling. They don't change between stored procs, there meaning if fixed but primary use is to help readability and have a consistent style.

```
-- Declare code that resolve to possible Error
DECLARE @CONFLICT_CODE AS INT 
SET @CONFLICT_CODE= -99

-- Check for Conflict
IF Found > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT  @Error = @CONFLICT_CODE
END
```

I would be great to define these in a file that I could include into the stored proc.

I'm developing on SQL Server 2008 deploying to SQL Server 2005

Comment: Even if you could declare them in a file (or perhaps a table) that was "included" in the sproc, how would you know which one from the file to choose for which sproc? You'd still have to have something hard-coded in the sproc to select the right one of the file, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this in TSQL. Another way, there is no include or macro feature

However, you could create a UDF thus:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CONFLICT_CODE()
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN -99
END
```

This would replace this in every proc

```
-- Declare code that resolve to possible Error
DECLARE @CONFLICT_CODE AS INT 
SET @CONFLICT_CODE= -99
```

and you'd use this

```
SELECT  @Error = dbo.CONFLICT_CODE()
```

Comment: Thanks, I considered this before but this would be a performance hit.

I'm goiung to see how much of a hit and get back to you

Comment: Over a 100000 loop the difference is ~.5 second on my slow Development VM.

So I believe what youhave suggested is fine and I think I'll move to it, Thanks

Comment: One half second differennce over how long total please?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't an include capability, but you may be able to minimize the effort to add your standard code.

You can add your code to a file, open the file when you need the standard code, and copy and paste the code.

You can also create a template file.  In SQL Server Management Studio, you can create templates and load the template when you want to create a new stored procedure.  Upon loading a template, your standard code would appear in the query tool.  It becomes the starting point for coding your new stored procedure.

Comment: I copy and paste it from existing Stored Procs, I'll look into the Template